# Find a good supremum as you can for probability $P (X≤-1)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable whose possible set of values ​​is: $$Ω_X = \{- 5, -4, -3, -2, -1,0,1,2,…, 10\}$$

In addition it is given that $E(X) = 6$.

Find a good supremum as you can for probability $P(X≤-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution.  Only values with non-zero probabilities are $-1$ and $10$.  To get $E(X)=6$, set $P(10)=\frac{7}{11}$ and $P(-1)=\frac{4}{11}$, so sup for $P(X\le -1)=\frac{4}{11}$.

Comment: why you only chose -1 and 10 ? why there is no better sup? thank u

Comment: For simplicity consider cases where there are only two possibilities for $X$.  If the upper one is less than $10$, it will need more weight to keep the mean at $6$.  Similarly if the lower one is less than $-1$, the upper will need more weigt to maintain $6$ for the mean.  More than two possibilities can be analyzed as two groups,  $\gt -1$ and $\le -1$.  To keep the mean at $6$, and maximize the probability of the lower group, each group will be at its maximum.